# Pros and cons of a typesetting options for questions and answers which renders the LaTeX apparence

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was wandering why when typing a question or an answer on tex.stackexchange, there wasn't an option to render something which looks like the result of the compilation of a .tex document especially for the math mode. I haven't been able to find any discussion related to this idea that is why I am asking this rather "material" question.

I came out with the following pros and cons but I am pretty sure that I am missing a lot of arguments here. Could you complete these list?

Pros:

- It would simplify some operations by removing the including of pictures generated with a .tex document in order to show some results of a code.
- It would help to have nicer questions and answers dealing sometimes formulas.

Cons:

- The results displayed will be different from something compiled with arbitrary packages, fonts and so on, which might introduce bias in questions/answers.
- tex.stackexchange is more oriented toward TeX code explanation and correction which does not require mathematical formulas.

Do you think that it would improve partially tex.stackexchange to have this option if it is used properly according to the previous pros and cons?

Comment: See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181/can-we-turn-off-math-tex-please and http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths

Comment: We don't like TeX here so we turned it off:P

Comment: This is a duplicate of the links @cgnieder showed. There would only be cons. and no pros It would not help when discussing TeX code to show the rendering by a system that doesn't use TeX.

Comment: I'd add that TeX is more than mathematics: many people using the site are not in the 'serious maths' area (I'm a synthetic chemist).